# JavaScript vs AS3 for Interactive Globe

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, actionscript-3

I am developing a web application that should display data points below the Earth's surface. It should also include user navigation, zoom, and rotational capabilities. It reads in the data from a XML file and should display 500-1000 spheres. Ideally, I would like to use HTML5, but it doesn't run in IE8. 
This is a Flash application that is somewhat similar to what I want (minus the globe around the spheres): 
http://demo.tufat.com/applets/molecule/index.html

There is also a good jQuery application that allows for 3d rotation out there.

So, the question is JavaScript/jQuery or AS3? I know Flash handles large amounts of data better but is Flash dying out? The application must run efficiently on most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

[Flash is not dying](http://isflashdeadyet.com/). I am not sure which Blogging Social Media Expert told you that.

Choose a language and just stick with it. Unless you know how to handle your memory and work with Paper Vision or Unity you should go with JavaScript for most likely you will end up with leaks if you do not do garbage collection, 500-1000 spheres is alot.